# Creating a new column based on if condition but getting error in python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

i want new column ['pred_n'] to be created based on certain condition, condition is as follows:
if year is less than or equal to current year & month is less than current month, pred_n should be equal to yhat*pct else it should be yhat*pct_ft. trying following syntax:

```
if((dfyz['year_x'] <     datetime.now().year) | ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) & (dfyz['mon'] < datetime.now().month))):
    dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct']
else:
    dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']
```

but i am not getting anything for else condition

Comment: You need to use df.loc. For example, df.loc[your_condition, column_to_update] = updated_value

Comment: i am not sure how that will help, I am able to get rid of error but now it is not checking if and else condition                                      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201432/if-else-not-checking-both-of-the-conditions-in-python