# if else not checking both of the conditions in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

i want new column ['pred_n'] to be created based on certain condition, condition is as follows: if year is less than or equal to current year & month is less than current month, pred_n should be equal to yhatpct else it should be yhatpct_ft. trying following syntax:

```
if((dfyz['year_x'] < datetime.now().year) | ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) & (dfyz['mon'] < datetime.now().month))):
    dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct']
else:
    dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']
```

but output shows only if condition though in my data I have month and year from 2019 - 08 onwards
and if i use

```
if ((dfyz['year_x'] < datetime.now().year) | ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) & (dfyz['mon'] < datetime.now().month))):
     dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct']
elif (((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) & (dfyz['mon'] >= datetime.now().month)) | ((dfyz['year_x'] > datetime.now().year))):
       dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']
```

it gives output only for else condition

Comment: Use `or` instead of `|` and `and` instead of `&` in Python expressions. Also consider writing `now = datetime.now()` and replacing all those calls in the expressions. Together, these will make your logic much easier to read (and reason about)”.

Comment: with or, and it shows following error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Decompose your conditions using variables (also helps to fix `now()` to a definite point in time for all your comparisons). Choose the variable names wisely so the expresisons are easier to read. And yes, Python logical opertors are `and` `or` `not`

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using the **bitwise** operators `|` and `&`, rather than the **logical** operators `or`and `and`.  Presumably you really want something like:

```
now = datetime.now()
if (dfyz['year_x'] < now.year or        
    dfyz['year_x'] == now.year and dfyz['mon'] < now.month
):
    ...
```

(Its not great practice to keep calling `now` several times ... each of your calls is potentially returning a **different** value for now)

Comment: or, and it shows following error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().                                                                   now =  datetime.now()      
if ((dfyz['year_x'] < now.year) or ((dfyz['year_x'] == now.year) and (dfyz['mon'] < now.month))):
     dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct']
elif (((dfyz['year_x'] == now.year) and (dfyz['mon'] >= now.month)) or ((dfyz['year_x'] > now.year))):
       dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']