# new column creation based on values of another column using if- else condition on python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying in following was

```
import numpy as np        
conditions = [
        (dfyz['year_x'] < datetime.now().year),
        ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) and (dfyz['mon'] < datetime.now().month)),
        (dfyz['year_x'] > datetime.now().year),
        ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) and (dfyz['mon'] >= datetime.now().month))
        ]   
values =  [dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct'], dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct'], dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft'], dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']]
dfyz['pred_n'] = np.select(conditions,values)
```

but I am getting the following error

```
f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried in another way also and posted in StackOverflow but there was no success so far
[if else not checking both of the conditions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201432/if-else-not-checking-both-of-the-conditions-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the logical operators *and*/*or* with `pandas.Series` as they will test the truth value of the series (basically calling `bool(dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year)` in your case - which will fail -> `ValueError`). The reason is, you essentially have an array of booleans, which might contain both `True` and `False`, this is why it suggests you to aggregate the values (`any`, `all` etc.).

However, you can use bitwise operations like `|` (for or) or `&` (for and) on the series. In the `numpy`/`pandas` world these bitwise operations refer to *element-wise comparisons*.

You can find more background on the technical reasons in [PEP-535](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/) discussing *Rich comparison chaining*. This PEP also gives some hope that things might change in the future.

Alternatively, `pandas.DataFrame` provides a great method called [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) which allows you to query the dataframe in a more uncluttered way, enabling you to refer to your columns directly and to use the classic logical operators.

```py
result = df.query("(name == 'abc') or (age < 25)")
```

You can access variables in the string by prefixing them with `@`. For example, you could do `now = datetime.now()` and refer to it via `@now` in the query string.